# Are Windows Phone 8 (and by extension Windows 8 Metro Apps) required to adhere to the Microsofts Design Guideline?

Tags: html, windows-phone-8, microsoft-metro

After a thorough search through the Microsoft Documentation i wasn't able to find a conclusive answer to the Question, wether or not an App published to the Windows Store has to look like a Metro/Windows Phone App or if it is allowed (but obviously discouraged) to have apps look like Ports from other Operating Systems. This Question obviously becomes very important when writing Cross Plattform HTML 5 Apps.

Have i overlooked something in the Documentation? Do you have any experience in this area?

Comment: yes it should follow the uniquness which windows phone have

Comment: can you quote me any source for this? i've been looking for hours now for anything from microsoft that states that explicitly (and their own Facebook App ignores that pretty much)

Comment: it is facebook so it can

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/fa00461b-abe1-41d1-be87-0b0fe3d3389d(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding for the phone is that in theory you can do what you want but within certain parameters. So if you want your app to look like an Android or iOS app with the back button at the top, that's fine. You don't have to use panoramas or pivots if you don't want to. You don't even have to use the set fonts if you don't want to.

But you cant start recreating desktop style windows drop downs, and other things that really wont work on a phone.

You also have to ensure your app still functions as a windows phone app. So the back button must work even if you have an on-screen back button.

For Windows 8 apps, I believe there much more strict. Pre 8.1 all apps had to use the search button on the charms rather than implementing there own. Since 8.1 the search button requirements have changed. Don't know about any other restrictions.

There's certainly no requirement to use flat colours rather than gradients like you would get on other platforms.